# How can I run my phpunit tests while travis builds my docker containers?

Tags: docker, mariadb, phpunit, travis-ci, php-8

I develop a symfony5 project on php8 in docker containers, which uses mariadb as project db and another one as test db. I would like to run my unit tests with every deployment so I can check the  minimal code coverage.

All tutorials I find seem to use no docker container like this one: https://blog.travis-ci.com/2021-07-01-tests-laravel and I cannot work out to get a test db running on travis.

Checks like phpCodesniffer or phpstan are no problem and I got them working with

```
    - docker run $IMAGE:$TRAVIS_COMMIT /bin/sh -c "bin/phpcs"
    - docker run $IMAGE:$TRAVIS_COMMIT /bin/sh -c "bin/phpstan analyze -c phpstan.neon.dist --memory-limit=1G"
```

Of course they need no database.

```
    - docker run $IMAGE:$TRAVIS_COMMIT /bin/sh -c "bin/console do:mi:mi -n"
    - docker run $IMAGE:$TRAVIS_COMMIT /bin/sh -c "bin/console do:fi:lo -n"
    - docker run $IMAGE:$TRAVIS_COMMIT /bin/sh -c "bin/phpunit --configuration=phpunit.xml.dist"
```

complains unsurprisingly, that it doesn't find a database.

**How can I setup a test db using either mysql or mariadb (no sqllite!) to get my tests running?**

As far as I have analysed so far the problem is that php and the database don't run in the same container so phpunit cannot connect to the database if I trigger the tests via "docker run ..." from outside. Locally I avoid this by using docker-compose and port mapping.

I can reproduce the behaviour locally if I try to start my tests from the bash outside of my container like this:

```
docker run my-local-php-container /bin/sh -c "bin/phpunit --configuration=phpunit.xml.dist"
```